# One color to category link depending on category ID

Tags: categories

I would like to style a category link depending on its ID, for instance, if the category ID is 2, then I want the link to be pink.

I cannot find a way to do the same thing to links. What type of solutions are available? Please be detailed in your reply as my coding knowledge is limited. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: what category links are you referring to? the ones from a category menu or categories widget? or the one from a post?

Answer (score 0):

Open the page which is rendering the category posts, and in the appropriate place (before running the loop) write the following code

```
<?php
$catid = get_cat_id();
$color = "#222"; //default;
if ($catid == $pinkCategoryId) $color = "#8B0A50";
else if ($catid == $redCategoryId) $color = "#FF0000";
?>

<style type = 'text/css'>
a { color: <?php echo $color;?>; }
</style>
```

Now adjust the code block above according to your need

You can also use it by category name instead of category id, just change the get_cat_id to get_the_category() which will return the current category name. Then you can perform the rest of the task as is

Comment: I am not insisting, but when an answer solves your problem please select the answer as accepted one.

Comment: Thanks for your help,
but should i replace $pinkCategoryId by an ID ?

Here is how i call the category link on the page:

<?php
$categories = get_the_category();
$separator = ' ';
$output = '';
if($categories){
 foreach($categories as $category) {
  $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
 }
echo trim($output, $separator);
}
?>

Comment: you can use category name too, see the answer above - I have edited

Comment: ok thanks, but the color doesn't work. could you please tell me if my code is correct ?


`<?php
$catid = get_the_category();
if ($catid == "typographie") $color = "#8B0A50";
else if ($catid == "signalétique") $color = "#FF0000";
else if ($catid == "édition") $color = "black";
else if ($catid == "identité visuelle") $color = "red";
?>
<style type = 'text/css'>
a { color: <?php echo $color;?>; }
</style>
<?
 foreach($catid as $category) {
 echo $category->cat_name . ' ';
 }

?>`